# Red Hat JBoss Deverloper Studio 11.3.0 GA

Tags: teiid

I am new to Teiid and I have been using Red Hat JBoss Deverloper Studio 11.3.0 GA with Teiid plugins, however, today i came across a web page talking about Teiid Syndesis, and this doesn't require any IDE as a web browser can be used.

Can someone suggest what is better Developer Studio or Teiid Syndesis?

Thank you,
Purnima Das

Answer (score 0):

You can check out https://syndesis.io/

But note that, Syndesis is not a replacement tool for Teiid Designer. It is an alternative tool for Integration which also has components from Apache Camel and suited for cloud environments. The Teiid portion is progressing, but still more to go. Keep watching this space for updates.

BTW, you do not need to use Teiid Designer or Syndesis to use Teiid. Even without tooling, you can design a VDB using DDL (using a text editor) in a much simpler model. If you are Java developer there are more options like using [Teiid Spring Boot](https://github.com/teiid/teiid-spring-boot/tree/master/samples/vdb) which are much more fully functional and upto date with Teiid functionality.